# Can't find link to logout from the forum?

Tags: support, login

Just signed up for Ask Ubuntu. Looks like a great community.

I am signed in. Closed all the windows, and the browser. When I open the site again, still signed in. I cannot locate a link to sign out of the forum!

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Top right corner, to the right of "help", looks a bit like a chat icon.